# Convert html to image (take a snapshot of dom)

Tags: javascript

We have a use case where we want to take an image of the content within a rich text editor (ckeditor). We are currently using html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which works fine to some extent but below are some issues we were facing:

a)Html2Canvas needs a proxy (wrote my own proxy in java) server to fetch images if the html has images hosted on a different server( the proxy is required due to cross domain restrictions), we have run into issues where the process of taking a image/snapshot takes a lot of time when there are a lot of images hosted on a different server. The time to take images is also effected if the url's are broken.

I was wondering if there is any reliable solution to taking images/snapshots of dom elements that also has cross browser compatibility and is fast.

Below is some research i did on some alternatives but need some advice.

PhantomJs: I looked at phantomJs which allows taking images outside the browser world but if felt using phantomJs might just be over doing as it requires a lot of build setup and its a whole different library to include.

svg based solution: I ran into this link (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) which shows taking snapshot by using svg element. I am not sure about the cross browser compatibility and how it would handle externally hosted images.

Comment: We had to write our own proxy in java as the library did not have one , it only had proxy's for node and python. We also wanted to take the exact image of the html content with the hosted images so the proxy could not be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is great, but their API is too verbose. If you want use PhantomJS but with friendly interface then look [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

You can capture website easily:

```
casper.start('http://www.google.fr/', function() {
    this.capture('google.png', {
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
});

casper.run();
```